# Change "page/x" wordpress permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I change the permalink of pagination?

I have something like this:

```
http://www.myblog.com/categories/my-category/page/2/
```

I want to remove the word "page" or change it with another word.

Comment: This might help you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57070/change-the-page-slug-in-pagination

Answer (score 0):

log into the back-end of wordpress and head onto: Settings->Permalinks

then click on custom structure add this to the bad ( thats how i have it atm)

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

You can fiddle around with it and make it just how you want it.

here are some extra taggs you could use:

```
 %year%
```

The year of the post, four digits, for example 2004

```
 %monthnum%
```

Month of the year, for example 05

```
 %day%
```

Day of the month, for example 28

```
 %hour%
```

Hour of the day, for example 15

```
 %minute%
```

Minute of the hour, for example 43

```
%second%
```

Second of the minute, for example 33

```
 %post_id%
```

The unique ID # of the post, for example 423

```
%postname%
```

A sanitized version of the title of the post (post slug field on Edit Post/Page panel). So “This Is A Great Post!” becomes this-is-a-great-post in the URI.

```
 %category%
```

A sanitized version of the category name (category slug field on New/Edit Category panel). Nested sub-categories appear as nested directories in the URI.

```
 %author%
```

A sanitized version of the author name.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Joel's answer I solved.

I've added this to function.php file of my template

```
function re_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->pagination_base    = 'pagina';
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 're_rewrite_rules');
```

and this to my .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/(.*)/page/(.*) /$1/pagina/$2
```